# how to make a variable seen in all views - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so i have many controllers and many views.

i want my variable @random_quote to be evaluated each time every view loads up.

i tried several things in application controller(i thought it should be here?) but none of them worked.

so how do i connect these two: `@random_quote.body (in view)`  and

`@random_quote = Quote.find(:random)`  (in controller right?)

to bee seen through all my application?

thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I doubt you actually need it to be accessible in all views. But you can put `@random_quote = Quote.find(:random)` under a method that is called with a `before_filter` in your ApplicationController. It will then be accessible everywhere.

Like so:

```
before_filter :get_random_quote
def get_random_quote
    @random_quote = Quote.find(:random)
end
```

Comment: it works this way thank you. i also realised i can also put it into application controller(without before filter). what is actually the difference. is it better to put it into helper? thanks again!

Comment: I assumed you wanted to generate the quote once per page view. If you want a new quote every time then you don't need the before_filter.